# Multiple Iframe rendering performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, iframe

I'm making little bit complex application which renders feeds from social networks in iframes. Every new feed is displayed as new 'brick'. I use grid system to animate whole process to make it look fluent. 
Node.js in backend and jQuery in frontend. 
The problem is- no browser can handle so much iframes rendering at the same time and stay fluent. The biggest problem is with facebook iframes beacuse their load IS TOO DAMN HIGH. 
I considered using velocity.js but it only solves animation performance problem. Is there any way to optimize iframe rendering process or work around it? Imagine streaming 50+ Iframes in window.